# How to programatically check if a particular version of flash player is installed or not using JavaScript.?

Tags: internet-explorer, flash, javascript, javascript-framework

I have a java script code and I want to check if flash player is installed or not and if at all it is installed which version ? 
Requirement demands me to achieve this  without using SWFObject. INstead I want to some simple javascript code. 
   I used the following snippet:

```
currentVer = new ActiveXObject("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.10");
        version = currentVer.GetVariable("$version");
```

But its throwing the error msg,

> File name or class name not found
>   during Automation operation

I want to achieve using javascript coding itself, without downloading any software for it like SWFObject.
I am using IE.
Kindly help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have most of it right there, you're just missing the testing part of it. Unfortunately there isn't really a way to access a given property that tells you what you want. You have to try to create the object.

```
function getFlashVersion(){
 var flash = 'None';
 // Count down from 10.
 for(var i = 10; i > 0; i--)
 {
   try{
    flash = new ActiveXObject("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash."+String(i));
   }catch(e){
     //console.log(e);
   }
   if(flash != 'None')
    return flash.GetVariable("$version");

 }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried with the code snippet you provided. But still its returning the value **"undefined"** and throwing the same error msg as      ** " File name or class name not found during Automation operation **. Can you let me know what is the fix for this. why its returning undefined?

Comment: It seems to be working then; successfully creating the objects that is. I'd say the flash.GetVariable is the culprit in this case. Throw in an alert(flash) just before the function returns. Uncomment the console.log(e) to see the try catch block in action.

Comment: When I uninstalled & reinstalled flash it suddenly started working. Really didnt understand why such inconsistency its showing. Actually I have 2 versions, 10.1.102.64 & 10.2.161.23. But its returning only 10.1.102.64 in the 1st iteration of the loop. Why is it not recognizing other one. I want my code to check if the version 10.2.161.23 is installed or not irrespective of other flash versions being installed or not. But its not happening. Can you kindly let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe has a whole kit for detecting and (optionally) upgrading the version of Flash, including HTML examples; you can find it [here](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/download/detection_kit/).

From that page:

> The Flash® Player Detection Kit helps developers implement robust player detection for a variety of deployment environments by providing a set of templates and techniques to successfully detect the version of Flash Player installed on a user’s computer, and, if needed, to then install the latest version of Flash Player. The kit also includes a detailed explanation and sample files for implementing the new, player-based Flash Player Express Install experience.