# IE 9 flash detect with javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

Checking if flash plugin present, failing only in IE (think its basically the javascript engine of IE 9, even when browser&document mode changed with developer tools).

```
var is_Flash = false;
var is_FlashVersion = 0;

var plugin = (navigator.mimeTypes && 
              navigator.mimeTypes["application/x-shockwave-flash"] &&
              navigator.mimeTypes["application/x-shockwave-flash"].enabledPlugin) ?
              navigator.mimeTypes["application/x-shockwave-flash"].enabledPlugin : 0;
if (plugin&&plugin.description) {
    is_Flash = true;
    is_FlashVersion = parseInt(plugin.description.substring(plugin.description.indexOf(".")-1));
}
```

IE doesnt return the plugin details.
Anyone know of a solution?

Can use this to check the object details, IE simply nothing and 0 length on the mimeTypes object.

```
var obj = navigator.mimeTypes["application/x-shockwave-flash"];
var out = '';
for (var i in obj) {
    out += i + ": " + obj[i] + "\n";
}
alert(out);
```

Comment: Have a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944110/how-to-programatically-check-if-a-particular-version-of-flash-player-is-installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at ActiveXObjects in ie.

I wrote this little function a while back, maybe you can get some inspiration from it, i have not tested it in ie9 however.-

```
function hasFlashVersionOrBetter(major, minor) {
    minor = minor || 0;
    var v;
    if (navigator.plugins && navigator.plugins.length > 0) {
        var type = 'application/x-shockwave-flash';
        var mimeTypes = navigator.mimeTypes;
        if (mimeTypes && mimeTypes[type] && mimeTypes[type].enabledPlugin && mimeTypes[type].enabledPlugin.description) {
            v = mimeTypes[type].enabledPlugin.description.replace(/^.*?([0-9]+)\.([0-9])+.*$/, '$1,$2').split(',');
        }
    }
    else {
        var flashObj = null;
        try { flashObj = new ActiveXObject('ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash'); } catch (ex) { return false; }
        if (flashObj != null) {
            var fV;
            try { fV = flashObj.GetVariable("$version"); } catch (err) { return false; }
            v = fV.replace(/^.*?([0-9]+,[0-9]+).*$/, '$1').split(',');
        }
    }
    if (v) {
        var majorVersion = parseInt(v[0], 10);
        return major > majorVersion || major == majorVersion && minor >= parseInt(v[1], 10);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: havnt tried this but it seems like it would work, so i'll set your answer as accepted.

Comment: Works, except your comparisons are backward, so it only returns true if it's less than the passed in version.  Should be:  major < majorVersion || major == majorVersion && minor <= parseInt(v[1], 10);

Answer (score 2):

Why to reinvent the wheel and have headache:
Use this lightweight JS library.

http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

You can detect flash or flash versions easily,without any cross browser issues,

Comment: FYI: swfobject team hasn't released anything since Jun 2009

Comment: And it doesn't work correctly in IE9 due to some security plugin restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

```
        if (navigator.plugins && navigator.plugins.length > 0) {
            var type = 'application/x-shockwave-flash';
            var mimeTypes = navigator.mimeTypes;
            if (mimeTypes && mimeTypes[type] && mimeTypes[type].enabledPlugin && mimeTypes[type].enabledPlugin.description) {
                //Flash Object found.
            }
        }
```

The above code is working in all the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for the response but my co-developer found a nice piece of code by adobe that works for all browsers.

```
// Flash Player Version Detection - Rev 1.6
// Detect Client Browser type
// Copyright(c) 2005-2006 Adobe Macromedia Software, LLC. All rights reserved.
var isIE  = (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE") != -1) ? true : false;
var isWin = (navigator.appVersion.toLowerCase().indexOf("win") != -1) ? true : false;
var isOpera = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera") != -1) ? true : false;

function ControlVersion()
{
    var version;
    var axo;
    var e;

    // NOTE : new ActiveXObject(strFoo) throws an exception if strFoo isn't in the registry

    try {
        // version will be set for 7.X or greater players
        axo = new ActiveXObject("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.7");
        version = axo.GetVariable("$version");
    } catch (e) {
    }

    if (!version)
    {
        try {
            // version will be set for 6.X players only
            axo = new ActiveXObject("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.6");

            // installed player is some revision of 6.0
            // GetVariable("$version") crashes for versions 6.0.22 through 6.0.29,
            // so we have to be careful. 

            // default to the first public version
            version = "WIN 6,0,21,0";

            // throws if AllowScripAccess does not exist (introduced in 6.0r47)     
            axo.AllowScriptAccess = "always";

            // safe to call for 6.0r47 or greater
            version = axo.GetVariable("$version");

        } catch (e) {
        }
    }

    if (!version)
    {
        try {
            // version will be set for 4.X or 5.X player
            axo = new ActiveXObject("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.3");
            version = axo.GetVariable("$version");
        } catch (e) {
        }
    }

    if (!version)
    {
        try {
            // version will be set for 3.X player
            axo = new ActiveXObject("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.3");
            version = "WIN 3,0,18,0";
        } catch (e) {
        }
    }

    if (!version)
    {
        try {
            // version will be set for 2.X player
            axo = new ActiveXObject("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash");
            version = "WIN 2,0,0,11";
        } catch (e) {
            version = -1;
        }
    }

    return version;
}

// JavaScript helper required to detect Flash Player PlugIn version information
function GetSwfVer(){
    // NS/Opera version >= 3 check for Flash plugin in plugin array
    var flashVer = -1;

    if (navigator.plugins != null && navigator.plugins.length > 0) {
        if (navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash 2.0"] || navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash"]) {
            var swVer2 = navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash 2.0"] ? " 2.0" : "";
            var flashDescription = navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash" + swVer2].description;
            var descArray = flashDescription.split(" ");
            var tempArrayMajor = descArray[2].split(".");           
            var versionMajor = tempArrayMajor[0];
            var versionMinor = tempArrayMajor[1];
            var versionRevision = descArray[3];
            if (versionRevision == "") {
                versionRevision = descArray[4];
            }
            if (versionRevision[0] == "d") {
                versionRevision = versionRevision.substring(1);
            } else if (versionRevision[0] == "r") {
                versionRevision = versionRevision.substring(1);
                if (versionRevision.indexOf("d") > 0) {
                    versionRevision = versionRevision.substring(0, versionRevision.indexOf("d"));
                }
            }
            var flashVer = versionMajor + "." + versionMinor + "." + versionRevision;
            //alert("flashVer="+flashVer);
        }
    }
    // MSN/WebTV 2.6 supports Flash 4
    else if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("webtv/2.6") != -1) flashVer = 4;
    // WebTV 2.5 supports Flash 3
    else if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("webtv/2.5") != -1) flashVer = 3;
    // older WebTV supports Flash 2
    else if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("webtv") != -1) flashVer = 2;
    else if ( isIE && isWin && !isOpera ) {
        flashVer = ControlVersion();
    }   
    return flashVer;
}

// When called with reqMajorVer, reqMinorVer, reqRevision returns true if that version or greater is available
function DetectFlashVer(reqMajorVer, reqMinorVer, reqRevision)
{
    versionStr = GetSwfVer();
    if (versionStr == -1 ) {
        return false;
    } else if (versionStr != 0) {
        if(isIE && isWin && !isOpera) {
            // Given "WIN 2,0,0,11"
            tempArray         = versionStr.split(" ");  // ["WIN", "2,0,0,11"]
            tempString        = tempArray[1];           // "2,0,0,11"
            versionArray      = tempString.split(",");  // ['2', '0', '0', '11']
        } else {
            versionArray      = versionStr.split(".");
        }
        var versionMajor      = versionArray[0];
        var versionMinor      = versionArray[1];
        var versionRevision   = versionArray[2];

            // is the major.revision >= requested major.revision AND the minor version >= requested minor
        if (versionMajor > parseFloat(reqMajorVer)) {
            return true;
        } else if (versionMajor == parseFloat(reqMajorVer)) {
            if (versionMinor > parseFloat(reqMinorVer))
                return true;
            else if (versionMinor == parseFloat(reqMinorVer)) {
                if (versionRevision >= parseFloat(reqRevision))
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

function AC_AddExtension(src, ext)
{
  if (src.indexOf('?') != -1)
    return src.replace(/\?/, ext+'?'); 
  else
    return src + ext;
}

function AC_Generateobj(objAttrs, params, embedAttrs) 
{ 
    var str = '';
    if (isIE && isWin && !isOpera)
    {
        str += '<object ';
        for (var i in objAttrs)
            str += i + '="' + objAttrs[i] + '" ';
        for (var i in params)
            str += '><param name="' + i + '" value="' + params[i] + '" /> ';
        str += '></object>';
    } else {
        str += '<embed ';
        for (var i in embedAttrs)
            str += i + '="' + embedAttrs[i] + '" ';
        str += '> </embed>';
    }

    document.write(str);
}

function AC_FL_RunContent(){
  var ret = 
    AC_GetArgs
    (  arguments, ".swf", "movie", "clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"
     , "application/x-shockwave-flash"
    );
  AC_Generateobj(ret.objAttrs, ret.params, ret.embedAttrs);
}

function AC_GetArgs(args, ext, srcParamName, classid, mimeType){
  var ret = new Object();
  ret.embedAttrs = new Object();
  ret.params = new Object();
  ret.objAttrs = new Object();
  for (var i=0; i < args.length; i=i+2){
    var currArg = args[i].toLowerCase();    

    switch (currArg){   
      case "classid":
        break;
      case "pluginspage":
        ret.embedAttrs[args[i]] = args[i+1];
        break;
      case "src":
      case "movie": 
        args[i+1] = AC_AddExtension(args[i+1], ext);
        ret.embedAttrs["src"] = args[i+1];
        ret.params[srcParamName] = args[i+1];
        break;
      case "onafterupdate":
      case "onbeforeupdate":
      case "onblur":
      case "oncellchange":
      case "onclick":
      case "ondblClick":
      case "ondrag":
      case "ondragend":
      case "ondragenter":
      case "ondragleave":
      case "ondragover":
      case "ondrop":
      case "onfinish":
      case "onfocus":
      case "onhelp":
      case "onmousedown":
      case "onmouseup":
      case "onmouseover":
      case "onmousemove":
      case "onmouseout":
      case "onkeypress":
      case "onkeydown":
      case "onkeyup":
      case "onload":
      case "onlosecapture":
      case "onpropertychange":
      case "onreadystatechange":
      case "onrowsdelete":
      case "onrowenter":
      case "onrowexit":
      case "onrowsinserted":
      case "onstart":
      case "onscroll":
      case "onbeforeeditfocus":
      case "onactivate":
      case "onbeforedeactivate":
      case "ondeactivate":
      case "type":
      case "codebase":
        ret.objAttrs[args[i]] = args[i+1];
        break;
      case "id":
      case "width":
      case "height":
      case "align":
      case "vspace": 
      case "hspace":
      case "class":
      case "title":
      case "accesskey":
      case "name":
      case "tabindex":
        ret.embedAttrs[args[i]] = ret.objAttrs[args[i]] = args[i+1];
        break;
      default:
        ret.embedAttrs[args[i]] = ret.params[args[i]] = args[i+1];
    }
  }
  ret.objAttrs["classid"] = classid;
  if (mimeType) ret.embedAttrs["type"] = mimeType;
  return ret;
}

DetectFlashVer(8, 0, 0);
```