# VBScript not executed correctly in window.execScript in IE 9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, vbscript

I know, IE 8 and 9 are out of date. But I need to check the flash plugin there. They don't provide a useful navigator.plugins array, so I looking for alternatives. One can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229830/ie-9-flash-detect-with-javascript).

Another one is something like this:

```
var a = void(0);
window.execScript("On error resume next: a = IsObject(CreateObject('ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.11'))", "VBScript");
console.log(a); //-> undefined
```

or:

```
var a = 'jess';
window.execScript("On error resume next: a = IsObject(CreateObject('ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.11'))", "VBScript");
console.log(a); //-> 'jess'
```

or:

```
var a = false;
window.execScript("On error resume next: a = IsObject(CreateObject('ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash'))", "VBScript"); //no version string here
console.log(a); //-> false
```

It seems like either *execScript* or the *VBScript* does not change the value of **a** at all.

I'm guessing, that there is an issue with the scope, in which this script is executed (there is no access to **a**) - or a similar problem. I've tried this piece of code in an anonymous function and in the console.

Does anybody ever hit that issue? Is there any explanation or solution? Thank you very much!

Comment: Additionally: is it true, that a will only be manipulated, if IsObject returns true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, the main issue was a missing line break in the VBScript (or in the JS string, which pretends to be VBScript).

Instead of:

```
window.execScript("On error resume next: a = IsObject(CreateObject('ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.10'))", "VBScript");
```

you must write:

```
window.execScript("On error resume next:\n a = IsObject(CreateObject('ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.10'))", "VBScript");
```

That works. I'm not familiar with Basic or VBScript, but I've thought about it and figured, that it will need a line break to know, that a new command follows.

I'm still **not sure**, whether the assumption is correct, that *window.execScript* or *IsObject* (VBScript) changes the value of the JS variable only, if the result is *true*.